# C++ template method specialization to return pointer or reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have this method

```
template <typename T>
T GetFnInput(){
  //.... here is obtained void * t value from some library
  return (T)(t);
}
```

And I have several template specializations for different types

```
template <>
uint32 GetFnInput<uint32>(){
    return 0;
}

template <>
bool GetFnInput<bool>(){
    return true;
}
```

However, I need a specialization for reference. I have tried this (the code is mess and should not be used in production, this is just for my testing purposes):

```
template <typename T, 
typename BaseT = std::decay<T>::type,
typename std::enable_if <std::is_reference<T>::value == true>::type* = nullptr >
T GetFnInput(){
  BaseT * t = new BaseT();
  return *t;
}
```

Plus I have add `typename std::enable_if <std::is_reference<T>::value == false>::type* = nullptr >` to original (above) `GetFnInput()`
But it wont compile, end with error:

> error C2244: 'GetFnInput': unable to match function definition to an
>   existing declaration

Comment: This function seems very strange: you're returning a _pointer_ (although the return type is `T`, not `T *`) or the value itself.

Comment: @ForceBru T is typename for pointer, value or reference (eg. T can be int, int * or int &)

Comment: I see, but the result of `new int()` would be `int *` and `new (int *)()` will yield a value of type `int **`, and those types are different

Comment: @ForceBru Oh.. I can see... that is a mistake. In my real code I have a different way to create new instance, so there is no new T(). I have edited the methods body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem is that you're missing `typename` here:

```
typename BaseT = std::decay<T>::type,
                ^^^
```

Once you have that, you have a second problem which is that the call to, say, `GetFnInput<int&>()` is ambiguous between the original function template `GetFnInput<typename>` and this new function template `GetFnInput<typename, typename, typename>`. These two function templates are overloads of each other and are otherwise unrelated.

Typically want you want to do is lift the template parameter into the argument list so it becomes easier to overload on:

```
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };

template <class T>
auto get() -> decltype(get_impl(tag<T>{}))
{
    return get_impl(tag<T>{});
}
```

And then you can write your `get_impl` function template much easier. Specific types are just specific overloads:

```
uint32_t get_impl(tag<uint32_t> ) { return 0; }
```

And reference types is just a template:

```
template <class T>
T& get_impl(tag<T& > ) { ???; }
```

---

Note that return a reference to an allocated pointer sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks.. I know about return ref to pointer is bad. For ill-formed method, that was a typo, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

You try is an overload, not a specialization.
As function cannot be partial specialized, I suggest to use struct instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct helper
{
    T operator() const { return {}; }
};

template <>
struct helper<bool>
{
    bool operator() const { return true; }
};

template <typename T>
struct helper<T&>
{
    T& operator() const { static T t; return t; }
};

template <typename T>
T GetFnInput(){
    return helper<T>{}();
}
```